# where did I accidentally move my files to?

Tags: command-line, files, delete, mv

I attempted to rename all `.el` files to the same name but without ending. I used the command `mv *.el ./*` in my terminal and now my home is pretty much empty. Any suggestions how to revert that or where to look for my files...? This might be a stupid question but I'm unsure where else to ask so I'd also be fine with getting re-directed here.

Comment: Run `echo .*`. Look for the last entry in the output.

Comment: Uh, sorry. Mean `./*`, not `.*`. The last entry would probably be the `Videos` folder.

Comment: Thanks that was it! There is a folder that contains it all. Thank you so much! Feel free to make this an answer and I'll gladly accept or is it too specific so that I should remove the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your home folder contains:

```
$ ls ~
1.el  10.el  2.el  3.el  4.el  5.el  6.el  7.el  8.el  9.el  Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Stuff  Templates  Videos
```

And you do `mv *.el ./*`; the command will likely expand to:

```
$ echo *.el ./*
1.el 10.el 2.el 3.el 4.el 5.el 6.el 7.el 8.el 9.el ./1.el ./10.el ./2.el ./3.el ./4.el ./5.el ./6.el ./7.el ./8.el ./9.el ./Desktop ./Documents ./Downloads ./Music ./Pictures ./Public ./Stuff ./Templates ./Videos
```

If you're lucky, the last entry could be a file and `mv` will complain. If you're unlucky, the last entry in the expanded list is a folder, `mv` will happily move all arguments to it. So, run `echo ./*` and look for the last entry (not that there will be many left).